# Firestore query single document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In a flutter app, I need to pull the users document from firestore only if the last updated field is greater then the last updated locally.

Currently this is what I do:

```
    QuerySnapshot usersData = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("lastUpdated", isGreaterThan: lastUpdatedLocally)
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
        .getDocuments();
    Map<String, dynamic> userData =
        usersData.documents.isEmpty ? {} : usersData.documents.first.data;
```

I have three questions:

1. Is it possible to do something like this in a `get` query for a single document, it doesn't seem right to query the whole collection knowing that the document id is the user id.
2. If not, can we do a query by the document id, something like: `.where(<documentId>, isEqualTo: userId)` instead of having a filed in the document called "userId".
3. And lastly, is it slower to do what I did here then to query a single document (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the document ID, you can certainly [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) a single document using a [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) instead of building a Query.

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(userId).get()
```

The performance difference is negligible.  Firestore queries all perform based on the total number of documents retrieved, not the number of documents in the collection.  A document get() like above is essentially the same as if you were to do a query on the document ID field using [FieldPath.documentId](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html) as the name of the field.

If you're trying to get the document only if a certain field matches, you will have to do a full query with `FieldPath.documentId`.  However, even a query that doesn't match any documents will still cost you a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify document ID when calling Firestore like this

```
var document = await Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('TESTID1');
document.get() => then(function(document) {
  print(document("name"));
});
```