# Firestore single doc get vs query performance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any performance difference between performing a `get` operation on a single document reference vs performing a query operation to retrieve that single document ? for example:
`collection('users').document('uid').get()` vs `collection('users').where('uniqueField', '==', 'uniqueValue').get()`
(given the query operation is performed on a unique value, ie only one document per value)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, first you will receive a document and from there you can extract a value, and in the second example, you will receive all the documents that contain this value

Comment: @TomaszVizaint thanks for your response. Let's say I enforce the uniqueness of that value (only 1 document per unique value)

Comment: That You receive only one document but query want search in all documents i don´t know is good for performance

Comment: @TomaszVizaint It actually doesn't matter.  In both cases, Firestore will use an efficient index to find the requested document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the third sub-question of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096011/firestore-query-single-document) and the corresponding answer.

Since your query returns only one document the answer to the above question applies: "**The performance difference is negligible.** Firestore queries all perform based on the total number of documents retrieved, not the number of documents in the collection".

For more info why Firestore is working like that I would suggest you watch the following [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2) about "How do queries work in Cloud Firestore?".